How to get a .net project to fail build if there are editorconfig errors?
I've changed the .editorconfig file in a project so that it an error should be shown when a block scoped namespace is used. I've got this to work, but I also want the build to fail when there are errors like this, is this possible? I thought EnforceCodeStyleInBuild would do this but it doesn't seem to work.
I've set EnforceCodeStyleInBuild to true.
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>

I've also set an error severity in the .editorconfig csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
